# How do I reset the "Document Viewer" (Evince) toolbar?

Tags: evince, reset

I have edited my toolbar but I don't know how to reset it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to reset your toolbar, you will need to delete the configuration file called `evince_toolbar.xml` which is stored in `~/.config/evince`:

[image: Delete $HOME/.config/evince/evince_toolbar.xml.]

Comment: I confirm. The file will be recreated as soon as you edit the toolbar again.